# Read a file in the external distribution before installing the files in install4j

Tags: install4j

I have a requirement to read a file that is in the external distribution before the "install Files" action is called during the installation. is it possible to read the file during the startup action or extract the file to a temp location and read it before the installation process?

Comment: Found the answer, It can be included under Custom Code & Resource files if it needs to be available before the "install files" action has run. I will try this and see whether it satisfies my needs

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, It can be included under Custom Code & Resource files if it needs to be available before the "install files" action has run.